# Proyecto Android con anuncios AdMob no me reconoce adListener

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, admob

Tengo un proyecto con anuncios AdMob y necesito que se ejecute una acción cuando el usuario cierra el anuncio. Para ello debo utilizar AdListener pero me da error de Unresolved Reference, como si no existiera. Voy a pegar la función completa que carga el anuncio:

```
fun cargarAnuncio(adRequest: AdRequest){
InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
    override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Ad was loaded.")
        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
    }

    override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
        Log.d("TAG", adError?.message)
        mInterstitialAd = null
    }
})

mInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
    override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Ad was dismissed.")

    }

    override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Ad failed to show.")
    }

    override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Ad showed fullscreen content.")
        mInterstitialAd = null
    }
}

// Aquí se produce el error "Unresolved Reference", en .adListener
mInterstitialAd?.adListener = object: AdListener(){
    override fun onAdClosed() {
        super.onAdClosed()
        startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, ResultActivity::class.java))
    }
}
```

mInterstitialAd está fuera de la función. He probado a añadirle y quitarle el interrogante, pero sigue sin funcionar.
También he probado a importar "import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener" pero sigue sin reconocerlo.

Comment: Hola @PacoPepe ya respondí algunas preguntas que tenías pendientes, si tienes duda me comentas, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No debes usar `adListener`  **debes usar `FullScreenContentCallback` para reconocer cuando se cierra el anuncio.**

Dentro de `onAdLoaded()` implementa lo siguiente:

```
       override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Ad was loaded.")
            mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd

            if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                //Muestra anuncio.
                mInterstitialAd?.show(this@MainActivity)
            } else {
                //Anuncio no esta listo para mostrarse.
            }


            mInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
                override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()
                    //Se cierra anuncio, abre ResultActivity.
                    startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, ResultActivity::class.java))
                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: Eso lo he probado pero no me cambia de activity, de hecho creo que llega a ejecutarse ese método cuando cierro el anuncio. Y si meto mInterstitialAd?.show en onLoaded, me marca error en el .show

Comment: Debe funcionar, revisa este ejemplo: https://github.com/Jorgesys/Admob-Instersticial   , realiza justamente lo que deseas.

Comment: Insisto, no me cambia de activity. Incluso en el proyecto que me has pasado tampoco me cambia de activity. Voy a grabar en vídeo el proyecto que me has pasado para que compruebes que no me cambia de activity y paso el enlace por aquí.

Comment: Aquí está, con el proyecto que de Jorgesys. Como se puede comprobar, no cambia de activity https://youtu.be/j5jnAf8x5RY

Comment: @PacoPepe es muy importante revisar el LogCat se imprime algo ahí? Acabo de revisar y si se imprime que detecta cuando se cierra